# jquery slide click link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, href

First, Sorry if I don't speak good English.

My question is how do I make a `div` slide when I click a link using jQuery?

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function slide(div) {
        if($(div).css('display') === 'none'){ 
            $(div).delay(300).slideUp(500);
            return false;
        } else { 
            $(div).delay(300).slideUp(500);
            return false;
        }  
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="slide('#div1');">Click here</a>

<div id="div1" style='display: none'>
    this will show
</div>
```

Does anybody have any idea what the problem is? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) is specifically for hiding elements.

If you want to specifically SHOW the div, use [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) to show.
You are also able to use [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) if you wanted to switch between showing / not showing.

Just change your `.slideUp(`'s to `.slideDown(`'s.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q54RR/1/)

Comment: Then you want slideToggle(). Change that JSfiddle to use slideToggle

Comment: Try and be more specific in your questions next time :)

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your function, you're always using `slideUp`, this way the `display` will never change

```
function slide(div) {
    if($(div).css('display') === 'none'){ 
        $(div).delay(300).slideDown(500);
        return false;
    } else { 
      console.log('2');
        $(div).delay(300).slideUp(500);
        return false;
    }  
}
```

Use `slideToggle` instead.

```
<a href="#" class="handler">Click here</a>

<div id="div1" style='display: none'>
    this will show
</div>

$('.handler').click(function() {
    $('#div1').slideToggle(500);
});
```